# Как получить имя и домен пользователя через Active Directory?

Tags: java, active-directory

Подскажите пожалуйста каким образом можно получить данные о пользователи через Active Directory?

Если есть какие-то статьи по данному вопросу, можно получить их в комментариях?

А если вообще не сложно, можно пример кода?

Comment: Если хорошо с английским, то http://jeftek.com/222/using-java-code-with-active-directory/

Comment: Спасибо) с английским не важно. Но в любом случае буду читать. 
А может есть еще какие-то примеры?

Comment: Вообще, везде реализуют связкой jndi+ldap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С помощью следующего кода удалось решить эту задачу.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws LdapException, NamingException{
    Hashtable<String, String> ldapEnv = new Hashtable<String, String>(11);
    ldapEnv.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
    ldapEnv.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL,  "ldap://ad.domain.com:389");
    ldapEnv.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
    ldapEnv.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "login@domain.com");
    ldapEnv.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "password");
    InitialDirContext ldapContext = new InitialDirContext(ldapEnv);
    // Create the search controls         
    SearchControls searchCtls = new SearchControls();
    // Specify the attributes to return
    String returnedAtts[]={"sn","givenName", "samAccountName","mail"};
    searchCtls.setReturningAttributes(returnedAtts);
    // Specify the search scope
    searchCtls.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);
    // specify the LDAP search filter
    String searchFilter = "(&(objectCategory=user)(objectClass=person)(samAccountName=userName))";
    // Specify the Base for the search
    String searchBase = "cn=users,dc=domain,dc=com";
    // initialize counter to total the results
    int totalResults = 0;
    // Search for objects using the filter
    NamingEnumeration<javax.naming.directory.SearchResult> answer = ldapContext.search(searchBase, searchFilter, searchCtls);
    // Loop through the search results
    while (answer.hasMoreElements()) {
        javax.naming.directory.SearchResult sr = answer.next();
        totalResults++;
        System.out.println(">>>" + sr.getName());
        Attributes attrs = sr.getAttributes();
        System.out.println(">>>>>>" + attrs.get("samAccountName"));
        System.out.println(">>>>>>" + attrs.get("mail"));
        //System.out.println(">>>>>>" + attrs.get("url"));  

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Active Directory прекрасно может работать как LDAP-сервер. Аттрибут с логином и доменом для пользователя называется `userPrincipalName`. Вот пример работы с AD через LDAP использую библиотеку [ldaptive](http://www.ldaptive.org/)

```
import org.ldaptive.*;
import org.ldaptive.auth.*;
import org.ldaptive.pool.BlockingConnectionPool;
import org.ldaptive.pool.PoolConfig;
import org.ldaptive.pool.PooledConnectionFactory;
import org.ldaptive.pool.SearchValidator;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;


public class LdapFeatureTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws LdapException {

        ConnectionConfig connectionConfig = new ConnectionConfig();
        connectionConfig.setLdapUrl("ldap://ad.example.ru:389");
        connectionConfig.setConnectionInitializer(new BindConnectionInitializer("admin@example.ru", new Credential("password")));
        DefaultConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new DefaultConnectionFactory(connectionConfig);
        PoolConfig pollConfig = new PoolConfig();
        pollConfig.setMinPoolSize(3);
        pollConfig.setMaxPoolSize(10);
        pollConfig.setValidateOnCheckOut(false);
        pollConfig.setValidatePeriodically(true);
        pollConfig.setValidatePeriod(3000);
        BlockingConnectionPool pool = new BlockingConnectionPool(pollConfig, connectionFactory);
        pool.setValidator(new SearchValidator());
        pool.initialize();
        PooledConnectionFactory cf = new PooledConnectionFactory(pool);
        SearchExecutor executor = new SearchExecutor();
        executor.setBaseDn("ou=test,dc=example,dc=ru");
        String userLogin = "testUser";
        SearchResult res = executor.search(cf, "(samaccountname=" + userLogin + ")",/*логин без домена*/"samaccountname",/*логин@домен*/"userPrincipalName", /*имя*/ "givenName", /*фамилия*/ "sn").getResult();
        Collection<LdapEntry> ents = res.getEntries();
        System.out.println("ents.size() = " + ents.size());
        for (LdapEntry le : ents) {
            System.out.println(le);
            System.out.println(new String(le.getAttribute("givenName").getBinaryValue()));
            System.out.println(new String(le.getAttribute("sn").getBinaryValue()));
            System.out.println(new String(le.getAttribute("samaccountname").getBinaryValue()));
            System.out.println(new String(le.getAttribute("userPrincipalName").getBinaryValue()));
        }
    }    
}
```

Значения для baseDN и данные аутентификации у тебя должны быть свои.

Comment: А как можно получить данные пользователя, который авторизовался на текущем компе?

Comment: @Vorobey.A это вопрос совершенно другой темы, дабы обычно на текущем компьютере AD отсутствует. Возможно лишь получить имя юзера при помощи `System.getProperty("user.name")`, и по нему искать остальные данные на сервере AD/

Comment: Я уже три дня мучаюсь с решением этой задачи( 
Я создал новую тему http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/542110/ помоги, если можешь, пожалуйста)
Твой код кстати не использовал, удалось по другому коду решить задачу с использованием AD. Но спасибо тебе