# Как с помощью Active Directory на сервере получить имя пользователя совершающего изменения в веб-сервисе браузере?

Tags: java, active-directory

Пишу веб-сервис для своего отдела на работе.
Бэкенд пишу на java с использованием jetty, servlet.

Есть код авторизации в Active Directory и поиска пользователя по ключевому слову - имени пользователя. Код работает, находит сведения о данном пользователе.

Но мне необходимо сделать следующее. 
Удаленный пользователь в корпоративной сети, залогинился при входе в свой комп, зашел на веб-сервис и сделал какие-то изменения в нем, а сервер получит его имя .

Подключение к серверу - удаленное.

Comment: Никак с помощью AD Вы не получите имя пользователя. С его помощью можно сделать аутентификацию и в авторизации задействовать. А получить имя можно только на jetty, если конечно прикрутили к своему веб-сервису какую-нибудь аутентификацию

Answer (score 1):

При входе в систему, система получает ID пользователя.
Пользователь должен залогиниться на портале, чтобы пользоваться его сервисами.
Значит есть ID на портале.
Доступ к порталу есть только из корпоративной сети?
Если да, то у нас есть ID-залогиненного пользователя + ID-портального пользователя, но пока нет соответствия между этими ID для всего множества пользователей.
Если для логина на портале используется как раз ключевое слово (логин пользователя на портале), то мы просто используем код поиска по этому ключевому слову и всё. Берём имя пользователя из АД по ключевому слову, при этом проверяем, что такой пользователь в сети АД сейчас активен.
Если ID активен и в АД и на портале, всё ок. Если ID активен только на портале, а в АД не входил - не даём ему доступ на портал.